# Choosing Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

Can someone please explain me the meaning of "For a very simple application it is certainly the case that Core Data adds some overhead (compare a vanilla Cocoa document-based application with a Cocoa Core Data document-based application), however Core Data adds significant functionality."

I found this in Core Data documentation.

I am having a small app which contains lot of images and certain set of data interlinked.

What kind of overheads I can come across if I choose Core Data for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that you pay a small performance penalty in that launchtimes may be ever-so-slightly longer; there's also slightly increased memory usage. Especially with the 3GS and 4, that wouldn't be something I would worry about though.

And if you have to work with a certain amount of data, the benefits of Core Data (fast object retrieval and persistence) certainly outweigh the added "overhead".

Comment: I think that there is also a cognitive "overhead" in using Core Data. Coming to it the first time, You will need to learn a new set of classes and functionality, as well as some standard mantras/idioms that will, at first, seem somewhat complicated.